# Auto Label Height in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, label, uilabel

I would like to adjust the height of label in my app.

[image]

I set **Number of Lines: 0** in Attribute Inspector. I made **Trailing, Leading and Top** constraints. 

I would like to get label height adjustment. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: How did you set the constraints and how do you want it to look when it is multi line?

Comment: try adding bottom layout with greater than equal to (>=) with some constant value.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever, You see the text  "Ledger, A ....." ? Actually, after "A" word, there has a sentence. So, i would like to show it automatically label height adjust.

Comment: @commando24, I tried your way. But it is not work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is set that label's `bottom` to the director's name label also set the `greater than equal to (>=)` constraints for your label height, So it will looks like this.

[image]

Now set the constrains for the director's name label to `leading`, `trailing` and `height` with `greater than equal to (>=)`. Now also set the Director heading label top to this director's name label. So you are having constrains for this label like this.

[image]

Now simply select the Director heading label and set the fixed width height leading and trailing, Don't forgot to set its top to Director's name label. So the final result give you like this.

[image]

**Note:** Don't forgot to set `numberOfLines` to `0` for both of your cast name label and director name label.

Answer (score 2):

If you have given constraints to your label then you have to write it like,

```
 self.lblText.numberOfLines = 0
 self.lblText.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
 self.lblText.sizeToFit()
```

This adjust your label based on your text string.